# DropDownList Issue in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, collections

How to get ID names of many DropDownList in aspx page in a Collection?

```
DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
    string s=ddl.ID;
    List<string> li = new List<string>();
    li.Add(s);
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean.  Your code seems to be successfully adding an element to a list.  What are you trying to do that isn't working?

Comment: I want to get all ID's of DropDownLists inside a List(Collection). This code is not working.  Getting null value at the End.

Comment: You are creating anew DropDownList and retrieving the ID property (which will be null at this point). What are you trying to do? Do you want to find out the Ids of some existing DDLs?

Comment: yeah you are right. DDLs already exist in design page. How to get ID's of existing DDL's inside a List if there are 100 DDLs? @BenRobinson

Comment: @user2096592: All IDs of *what* drop down lists?  Are you just asking how to reference controls on the page?  Those should be class-level members on the Page object, unless they're being dynamically created or part of some repeater control or something like that.  You need to be more specific.  Right now the code you've shown does exactly what we would expect it to do.  It creates a new `DropDownList` (which has no default `ID` value), then adds the `ID` value to a `List`.

Comment: @David ok sir. Can you tell me how to get IDs of existing DDLs inside a List?  Suppose there are 100 DDls

Comment: You can get all of the controls in a parent control by accessing the Controls collection, e.g. `var ddls = Page.Controls.OfType<DropDownList>();` be aware this will only get the direct children, if any controls have their own child controls then you need to recursively look through every controls collection of every control.

Comment: after that? again passing null value. var ddls = Page.Controls.OfType<DropDownList>();  this ddls variable will contains all IDs?

Comment: @user2096592 No, it will contain all the DropDownList controls that are direct children of the page. From there you could loop through or use Linq to obtain the ID's in a collection. I highly suspect however that this is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I don't see a good reason to obtain all the ID's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment on another question I understand your question is that you have added controls to the page and now you want to read all of them back. To do this you need to recursively read all the controls on the page and find the ones that are of type DropDownList, something a bit like the following:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var dropdownListIds = new List<string>();
    var allControls = GetControlsRecursively(this);
    foreach (var ctrl in allControls)
    {
        var ddl = ctrl as DropDownList;
        if (ddl != null)
        {
            dropdownListIds.Add(ddl.ID);
        }
    }
}

private List<Control> GetControlsRecursively(Control parent)
{
    var allControls = new List<Control>();
    foreach (Control child in parent.Controls)
    {
        allControls.Add(child);
        allControls.AddRange(GetControlsRecursively(child));
    }
    return allControls;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Can you tell me how to get IDs of existing DDLs inside a List? Suppose there are 100 DDls

You have a couple of options...

1. Get the ID of each control individually
2. Loop through the `Controls` collection and test if each element is of type `DropDownList`
3. Store the controls in a collection and select IDs from that collection

The first option is the most straightforward, and if you only have to do it once then it's probably the simplest:

```
var list = new List<string>();
list.Add(dropDownList1.ID);
list.Add(dropDownList2.ID);
list.Add(dropDownList3.ID);
list.Add(dropDownList4.ID);
// etc...
```

The second option is the least code, but also the least reliable.  It might look something like this:

```
var list = new List<string>();
foreach (var control in Controls)
    if (control is DropDownList)
        list.Add((control as DropDownList).ID);
```

However, this will *only* get controls which are immediate elements of the `Controls` collection.  If any of them are nested inside of other controls, this might not find them.  You could make it more recursive to address that, but that's only going to make it more brittle and error-prone most likely.

The third option is probably the best if you're going to be querying the list of `DropDownList` controls many times.  What you essentially do here is statically create a list of your controls at the class level for the page.  Something like this:

```
private List<DropDownList> MyDropDownLists { get; set; }

// the page constructor
public MyPage()
{
    MyDropDownLists.Add(dropDownList1);
    MyDropDownLists.Add(dropDownList2);
    MyDropDownLists.Add(dropDownList3);
    MyDropDownLists.Add(dropDownList4);
    // etc...
    // You might even extract all of this into a CollectDropDownLists function
}
```

Then any time you need to query that list, you can do so easily:

```
var listOfIDs = MyDropDownLists.Select(d => d.ID);
```

Comment: thanks...I choose second option and i can count total number of controls but not able to get DDLs ID

Comment: @user2096592: As stated in the answer, the second option is the *least reliable*.  It will "work" in the sense that you can get the `ID`s from the immediate children of the `Controls` collection, but it's not very robust for more complex control hierarchies.  I still recommend either the first option if you only have to query the values once or the third option if you have to query the values many times.